# Limit of an integral over a domain

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral

Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real-valued integrable functions over an unbounded domain $\Omega$. Suppose the following property hold:

For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a compact set $K$ depending on $\epsilon$ such that
$$
\int_{\Omega\setminus K}|f_n|\,dx<\epsilon\qquad\text{and}\qquad \int_{K}|f_n|\,dx<\epsilon,
$$
uniformly in $n$. Then can we say that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Omega}|f_n|\,dx=0?
$$

I think it should be true by splitting $\Omega= K\cup (\Omega\setminus K)$, but still not fully convinced. Can someone please explain in a bit more detail? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course it's true. Indeed, let $\varepsilon >0$ and $K$ compact s.t. $$ \sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\int_{\Omega \setminus K}|f_n|+\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\int_K|f_n|<\varepsilon .$$
In particular $$\int_\Omega |f_n|<\varepsilon ,$$
for all $n$ and thus $$\limsup_{n\to \infty }\int_\Omega |f_n|<\varepsilon .$$
Letting $\varepsilon \to \infty $ gives the wished result.